# XML to XML inner node structure transformation in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while.

I have an xml file:

```
<ParentNode>
 <RequirementGroup>
    <ID>id1</ID>
    <Requirement>
        <ID>id2</ID>
        <Description>value1</Description>
    </Requirement>
    <RequirementGroup pi="attribute">
        <ID>id3</ID>
        <Requirement>
            <ID>id4</ID>
            <Description>value2</Description>
        </Requirement>
        <Requirement>
            <ID>id5</ID>
            <Description>value3</Description>
        </Requirement>
        <Requirement>
            <ID>id6</ID>
            <Description>value4</Description>
        </Requirement>
        <Requirement>
            <ID>id7</ID>
            <Description>value5</Description>
        </Requirement>
        <RequirementGroup>
            <ID>id8</ID>
            <Requirement>
                <ID>id9</ID>
                <Description>value6</Description>
            </Requirement>
            <RequirementGroup pi="attribute">
                <ID>id10</ID>
                <Requirement>
                    <ID>id11</ID>
                    <Description>value7</Description>
                </Requirement>
            </RequirementGroup>
        </RequirementGroup>
    </RequirementGroup>
 </RequirementGroup>
</ParentNode>
```

and this is the XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template name="ExampleTemplate1">
    <ID>Something</ID>
    <Description>example</Description>
    <TypeCode>QUESTION</TypeCode>
    <ValueDataTypeCode>INDICATOR</ValueDataTypeCode>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ExampleTemplate2">
    <ID>Something</ID>
    <PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
    <xsl:if test="Requirement">
        <xsl:for-each select="Requirement">
            <Example>
                <xsl:call-template name="ExampleTemplate1"/>
            </Example>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ParentNode/RequirementGroup">
    <xsl:if test="RequirementGroup[@pi]">
        <Node1>
            <xsl:call-template name="ExampleTemplate2"/>
            <xsl:if test="RequirementGroup[@pi]">
                <Node1>
                    <xsl:call-template name="ExampleTemplate2"/>
                    <xsl:if test="RequirementGroup[@pi]">
                        <Node1>
                            <xsl:call-template name="ExampleTemplate2"/>
                        </Node1>
                    </xsl:if>
                </Node1>
            </xsl:if>
        </Node1>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

So, i want to transform the XML in different node names and also with the same values ( but now i skipped the value part, i just want to have the correct node structure).

Here is my output with this transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Node1>
<ID>Something</ID>
<PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
<Example>
    <ID>Something</ID>
    <Description>example</Description>
    <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
    <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
</Example>
<Node1>
    <ID>Something</ID>
    <PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
    <Example>
        <ID>Something</ID>
        <Description>example</Description>
        <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
        <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
    </Example>
    <Node1>
        <ID>Something</ID>
        <PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
        <Example>
            <ID>Something</ID>
            <Description>example</Description>
            <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
            <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
        </Example>
    </Node1>
  </Node1>
</Node1>
```

As you can see in the XML file, i have more than one  node group for some of the  nodes. Thats why, i created a template with a  loop to get all of them even if it is one or five. But the result is not the one i want.

**EDITED**

Desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ParentNode xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Node1>
    <ID>Something</ID>
    <PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
    <Example>
        <ID>Something</ID>
        <Description>example</Description>
        <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
        <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
    </Example>
    <Node1>
        <ID>Something</ID>
        <PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
        <Example>
            <ID>Something</ID>
            <Description>example</Description>
            <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
            <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
        </Example>
        <Example>
            <ID>Something</ID>
            <Description>example</Description>
            <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
            <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
        </Example>
        <Example>
            <ID>Something</ID>
            <Description>example</Description>
            <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
            <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
        </Example>
        <Example>
            <ID>Something</ID>
            <Description>example</Description>
            <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
            <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
        </Example>
        <Node1>
            <ID>Something</ID>
            <PropertyGroupTypeCode>Something</PropertyGroupTypeCode>
            <Example>
                <ID>Something</ID>
                <Description>example</Description>
                <TypeCode>Something</TypeCode>
                <ValueDataTypeCode>Something</ValueDataTypeCode>
            </Example>
        </Node1>
    </Node1>
  </Node1>
</ParentNode>
```

**The code i share is executable already and it is simplified.**

Also kindly, if there is a better way to do this, I would like to hear. Because when i do the transformation in this way, I dont know how to replace the values inside the nodes.

EDIT2:

For, example the XML1 and XML2 has different namespaces, to express their SchemaID, versions and so on.. XML1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
xmlns:espd="urn:com:grow:espd:02.00.00" xmlns:cac="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-
award:CommonAggregate" 
xmlns:ccv="urn:isa:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CCV-
CommonAggregateComponents-1" xmlns:cbc="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-
award:CommonBasic" xmlns:espd-
req="urn:grow:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ESPDRequest-1" 
xmlns:util="java:java.util.UUID">
```

XML2:

```
xmlns="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-award:QualificationApplicationRequest" 
xmlns:cac="urn:X-test:UBL:Pre-award:CommonAggregate" xmlns:cbc="urn:X-
test:UBL:Pre-award:CommonBasic" xmlns:espd="urn:com:grow:espd:02.00.00" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" 
xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" 
xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" 
xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" 
xmlns:util="java:java.util.UUID" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

The example node for XML1:

```
 <cbc:ID schemeID="CriteriaID" schemeAgencyID="EU-COM-GROW" schemeVersionID="1.0">
```

Example for XML2:

```
<cbc:ID schemeID="CriteriaTaxonomy" schemeAgencyID="EU-COM-GROW" schemeVersionID="02.00.00">
```

but, when i copy the namespaces from XML2 to my ( your suggested XSLT) file, (because in this way i was thinking it will automatically recreate the new ones just like in XML2 and will not be problem, the transformation will be okay). But it has a weird look somehow,

The Output is:

```
<cbc:ID xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccv-cbc="urn:isa:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CCV-CommonBasicComponents-1" xmlns:cev="urn:isa:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CEV-CommonAggregateComponents-1" xmlns:cev-cbc="urn:isa:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CEV-CommonBasicComponents-1" xmlns:espd="urn:grow:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ESPDResponse-1" xmlns:espd-cac="urn:grow:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ESPD-CommonAggregateComponents-1" xmlns:espd-cbc="urn:grow:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ESPD-CommonBasicComponents-1" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" schemeID="CriteriaID" schemeAgencyID="EU-COM-GROW" schemeVersionID="1.0">
```

In the Output, it adds all the namespaces next to the node.. Why? How can i convert the desired namespaces versions etc from one to another ? just like changing attirbutes of the nodes as it is in XML2.

Comment: Please edit your question and specify the output that you want in XML.

Comment: Hi, Joel thanks for you recommendation, I added the desired output which is actually the same with the first XML file but with different node names and some added child-nodes in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fully understand what you want, but from what I've grasp so far, you need an identity template, which is

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and templates to match `RequirementGroup` and `Requirement` nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="RequirementGroup">
    <Node1>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Node1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Requirement">
    <Example>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Example>
</xsl:template>
```

the `xsl:apply-templates` itself is recursive. The whole stylesheet is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RequirementGroup">
        <Node1>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Node1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Requirement">
        <Example>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </Example>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ParentNode">
       <ParentNode>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </ParentNode>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

just add additional templates to it to change the values.

Comment: Joel, thank you for solution. It is working but i have question: The XML1 and XML2 that i want to transform , they have some differences. For example some nodes are not existed in XML1 but have to be in XML2 , or the namespaces and versions are different. If i just apply templates, it doesnt apply the missing nodes or other stuff in structure. Thats why i tried to create my own templates and call them based on the structure. How can i fix this problem ? apply-templates are easy yes but they are not excatly same. Hope i could tell myself

Comment: If you could provide a minimal example that I can work on, that would be great. Include there the namespaces and everything that is in your current XML. Include also the desired output.

Comment: Joel, I tried to explain the problem above, hope it is also clear for you. I really appreciate your help.. I am here to help you to understand problem if you have more questions. Thank you !

Comment: I see, just add  **exclude-result-prefixes="#all"**, after the last namespace declaration.

Comment: Joel,I tried it before it doesnt work.Some namespaces are still there

Comment: I actually dont want to get rid of them by exluding, i want to transform them like in the example that i provided

Comment: I have edited my answer. Just create a template for the root node and create another node (not just xsl:copy) even if it has the same name. This way the namespaces would transfer to the root node.